# Improving IE8 Performance with select2 v3.4.8 Library

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, internet-explorer-8, jquery-select2

I am trying to improve performance of the select2 v3.4.8 library in IE8.

Essentially, I have narrowed the problem down to the call from the SingleSelect2's opening method to the parent AbstractSelect2's opening method.  The method call I am speaking of is this one:

```
this.parent.opening.apply(this, arguments);
```

I have seen this call take upwards of 5 seconds to complete.  In some instances, it has taken up to 10 seconds to open the dropdown in IE8.

I've made some performance improvements already.  For example, rather than constantly adding the:

```
<div id="select2-drop-mask" class="select2-drop-mask"></div>
```

to the DOM programmatically, I just added it directly to the markup and set it's display:none.  This saves quite a number of cycles because apparently, adding elements to the DOM in IE8 is expensive to do from Javascript.

But I still want to get more performance improvements than this.  We have only increased performance by about 10-20% by making this change.

Does anyone have any suggestions for me?

We've already cached the data to display in the dropdown on the client on page load.  So, there are zero server calls being made when the dropdown is opening. The performance bottleneck is entirely inside the select2 library itself.

Unfortunately, we are unable to upgrade our select2 library.  Doing so would be at least an 8-Point User Story, so it's prohibitive at this time for us to undertake an upgrade.

Thanks to anyone who's able to help!

-classTemplateT

Comment: Upgrade to 3.5.2 and see if the problem goes away.  If it does, find out what they changed.

Comment: 3.4.8 is incredibly outdated (and I feel bad if you are locked to it), there were some significant performance boosts in newer versions of Select2.